# Dynamic JPanel with objects not displaying

Tags: java, user-interface, dynamic, jpanel

Can someone take a look at this part of my code and tell me why it won't return the objects inside the JPanel? It definitely goes inside the loop since I tried printing statements inside. Also this JPanel object is being put inside a TabbedPane just for clarification. Let me know if I need to explain in more detail or show more code to find a solution. Thanks.

```
JPanel createTipTailoringPanel(TipCalcModel model)
{

    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    int size = model.getNumOfPeople();
    content.removeAll();
    content.updateUI();
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,4));

    JTextField text[] = new JTextField[size];
    JSlider slider[] = new JSlider[size];
    JLabel label[] = new JLabel[size];
    JLabel cash[] = new JLabel[size];


    if(size == 0)
    {
        return content;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            text[i] = new JTextField();
            slider[i] = new JSlider();
            label[i] = new JLabel("$");
            cash[i] = new JLabel();
            content.add(text[i]);
            content.add(slider[i]);
            content.add(label[i]);
            content.add(cash[i]);
        }

        return content;
    }


}
```

Here is my calling method and the actionlistener that I use to pass in the numberofpeople:

```
 TipCalcView(TipCalcModel model)
{
    setTitle("Tip Calculator");
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Main Menu", createMainPanel());
    tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(0);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Tip Tailoring", createTipTailoringPanel(model));
    tabbedPane.addTab("Config Panel", createConfigPanel());

}

class GuestsListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        int userInput = 0;
        try{
            userInput = m_view.getGuests();
            m_model.setNumOfPeople(userInput);
            m_view.createTipTailoringPanel(m_model);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfex)
        {
            m_view.showError("Bad input: '" + userInput + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the code that calls this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your problem is outside of the code you listed. Here's a simplified working example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    DynamicJPanel dynamic = new DynamicJPanel();
    frame.add(dynamic.createTipTailoringPanel(3));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

JPanel createTipTailoringPanel(int size) {
    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        content.add(new JTextField());
        content.add(new JSlider());
        content.add(new JLabel("$"));
        content.add(new JLabel());
    }

    return content;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it had something to do with my JFrame not being correctly implemented.

Answer (score 3):

First, since you don't use the arrays anywhere, it could be shortened to:

```
JPanel createTipTailoringPanel(TipCalcModel model)
{

    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    int size = model.getNumOfPeople();
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,4));

    if(size == 0)
    {
        return content;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            content.add(new JTextField());
            content.add(new JSlider());
            content.add(new JLabel("$"));
            content.add(new JLabel());
        }
        return content;
    }
}
```

Second, seems like you add an empty components to the panel, maybe that's what you actually get?

Third, add you need to add the `content` panel to the JFrame (or other container) once it returns from the method above.

Comment: fourth & fifth, the calls to `removeAll()` and `updateUI()` are superfluous.

Comment: @afk - you are right, I copied without looking at that, since the array bothered me. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Oh your right I don't really need the array's, though when I tried the program after I changed the code it still doesn't show anything Ill edit my main post and show my code where I call this method. I also commented out the removeall and updateUI.

Comment: @Novazero - this seems like the problem is outside this method, as @WhiteFang34 said, we need to see the method that calls this one...